# Как найти строки с русскими символами?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Как найти строки в которых есть русские символы.
Допустим, есть строки:

```
Строка1-ABC 
QWE-строка 
example-string 
string-10101
```

Надо из этого достать строки в которых есть русские символы.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
$array = array('Строка1-ABC', 
               'QWE-строка',
               'example-string',
               'string-10101');
               
foreach($array as $string) {
    if (preg_match('/[а-яА-ЯёЁ]/', $string)) {
        echo "$string\n";
    }
}
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cf4167f95ae9888b5dc46af58fb3b8122cfd2174

Comment: Спасибо. Я искал способ чисто регуляркой. Не спал давно, голова даже не додумалась до цикла :)

Comment: Если ответ вам помог, примите его, нажав на зелёную галочку слева.